# Is there any way to get the existing subdirectories and files from an URL?

Tags: javascript, html, bash, web, networking

Imagine you have your file with url http://my.page/folder_1/file_1.php

I want to know if there's some software/command/script to get the subfolders/files given an url.

For example:

Input argument: `http://my.page/folder_1/`

Output:

```
http://my.page/folder_1/file_1.php [file]
http://my.page/folder_1/folder_1a  [dir]
```

I don't even know if that's possible, but hope for it to be

**Thanks for the help!**

Comment: When you visit a `directory` of the website, the behavior is defined in the server side. It 
 is not a file system. The server can return anything he want for the `url` you visit, I don't think you can always get the subfolders/files.

Answer (score 0):

Xiaofeng has it right, the ability to retrieve directories of files is up to the server implementation.  Often,  professional web sites have this directory listing disabled. Nonetheless, you still can give it a go.  The web server will respond with a 404 response if the  directory listing is not enabled/supported.

That said, I stole a little bit of code from [here](https://gist.github.com/antoineMoPa/ada42dcfc96197e38dc8c4df363aed72)

```
curl -silent $1 | grep href=\" | grep "http://" | grep -o "http:\/\/[^\"]*"
```

Essentially, the code looks for an href tag with an http:// link and then extracts the URL (`grep -o` returns only the matching portion of the line).   Since we are using a line based parsing to extract URLs from HTML source, we cannot call this code general - a proper HTML parser should be employed if you want more robust code.

What remains is for you to replace $1 with an expression that takes a URL and removes the file name.  Here's the code for that:

```
DIR=${URL%/*}/
```

The above code will remove the shortest matching pattern at the end of the URL that starts with a '/'.  For example:

```
URL="http://my.page/folder_1/file_1.php"
DIR=${URL%/*}/
echo $DIR  # outputs http://my.page/folder_1/
```

Putting it all together, you can have a script like this:

```
URL="$1"
DIR="${URL%/*}/"
curl -silent "$DIR" | grep href=\" | grep "http://" | grep -o "http:\/\/[^\"]*"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was not useful in my context, though. But I'm sure it must be in some other problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use  **scandir()**  function, which is used to return an array of files and directories of the specified directory. The scandir() function lists the files and directories which are present inside a specified path.

**Syntax:**

```
scandir(directory, sorting_order, context);
```

**Example:**

```
// specifying directory 
$mydir = '/folder_1'; 

//scanning files in a given diretory in ascending order 
$myfiles = scandir($mydir); 

//displaying the files in the directory 
print_r($myfiles);
```

**Output:**

```
 Array
(
[0] => terms.php
[1] => index.php 
[2] => contact.php
[3] => aboutus.php
[4] => ..
[5] => .
)
```

**Read PHP | scandir() Function's details here:**
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-scandir-function/